# How to calculate disk space on remote server and store values using ssh2 & node.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ssh2-sftp

Currently I'm using SSH2 and node.js to monitor disk space and partitions over remote server. And printing output to console. But the output is in string format so I couldn't store free space / total space value in any variable. 
Current I'm running **df -k** command using **con.exec** in **node.js(ssh2)** to run command over remote servers using credentials.

1. So How would it would be possible(store disk space in variable).
2. My Final task is to check disk space over remote server and generate alert if it is < 25%.
3. And also for HTML part I'm using AngularJs. So I've to give a button over web page to force check and for generating alert for users.

I've added the output format I'm receiving over console(both) below

[image: Shell Console Output]
[image: Browser Console Output]

Comment: To Everyone Pls stop down voting the question. It may be the butter task for you all but I'm new to node so it's a bottle neck task for me. So pls get me rid out this situation.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df -h | grep sd` to select only the row of the HDD's main partition.

After that, in data content of result array (see your picture, first item of array "data":"RESULT") change the sequence of space to one space. For example after `Filesystem` in your uploaded picture there are 4 spaces, replace them with one space.

In the final string you sill have a result like this: `/dev/sda1 609G 202G 376G 35% /`

Now, you should split this string whit space char. Resulting in the array:
`item[0] is Filesystem`
`item[1] is total space`
`item[2] is used space`
`item[3] is available space`
`item[4] is used space in percent form`
`item[5] is mounted on path`

**Very very important note**: I suggest you do not use this methodology, because it is **NOT** secure (look at your picture).

Anyone can find it by tracing with a **firebug**!

Comment: An Awesome explanation with answer but i'd have request that please remove the username and password u mentioned in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,
if you are using linux system there is command "df -h | grep sd" to find out disk space i am sure there must be command for windows also
"child_process" module in js helps to run system commands . to find disk space details use following code .

```
let command = `df -h | grep sd`;
child_process.exec(command, (err, stdout, stdin) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Err", err)

    }
    console.log("Out", stdout.split(/[ ,]+/));

});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/26984323)